# creating a class-subject database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i want to create a school database and i am stuck up in middle. i have following tables

1. **users** - id, role_id, username, password
2. **roles** - id, role(*teacher/student*)
3. **teachers**- id,
4. **student** -  id, class_id,
5. **class** - id, standard_id, section
6. **standard** - id, name

Now i wish to relate subject to teacher and student. The problem here is that

1. Some subjects are optional and others compulsory
2. English for 5-7th standard is compulsion but optional for 8-10
3. For 8th std. English is part of 3rd subject / optional group 3 for 9-10 english can be taken as subject1, subject2 or subject3 but only once and English as subject 1 is different from English as subject 2.

i wish to relate students to his subjects.

Also for 8std section A & B(*std + section = class*)  English is the 3rd subject for 8c it's fixed German but 8D can have both. It would be great if this data could could also be associated in some way not necessary to same table. This is some thing like allowed subjects for class.

i would also like to associate teacher to subject and class (teacher X takes english for 8c)

Comment: I found it hard to understand exactly  what your question is. I think others have given some good answers below, but I have some general advice. Don't think about the database schema until you have clearly defined the objects in your domain and the business logic. I think you're confusing yourself by getting database jargon confused with business logic. First decide what information **actually matters** to your application, and exactly what the rules will be. Then write classes that will encapsulate that information and the behaviour behind it. Then design your database schema last.

Answer (score 4):

your issue seems to be easily solved by using the following tables:

**student**

- id
- class_id

**teacher**

- id

**class**

- id

**subject**

- id
- grade
- optional
- requires_subject_id

**course**

- id
- teacher_id
- subject_id
- school_year

**course_attendants**

- course_id
- student_id

as you can see, the constraints if a subject is optional or compulsory are defined in table subject. a subject can be held by a teacher in a course and a school year. finally a course can be attendet by scholars as described in table course_attendants. to check if a student has already taken a course in the past, you must only check table course_attendants and course. to design that a course could only be attended if another course was already visited put the required course id in field requires_subject_id in table subject.

Comment: please not English as subject 3 is different from English as subject 2 so is English diffrent b/w school year

Comment: @WebDeveloper: Then it sounds like you should treat those as different subjects that just happen to have the same name.

Comment: I would split requires_subject_id into another pivotal table because some subjects might one day have more than one prerequisite.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between a student and a subject or a teacher and a subject should be stored in a different "course_relationships" table. For compulsory subjects by class, add SQL to the function you use to create students that subsequently creates relationships for each compulsory subject. Something like:

```
// after whatever function you're using to create users

$compulsory_classes=array();

// for sixth grade
$compulsory_classes['6'] = array();

// for sake of example, say English course ID is 1
$compulsory_classes['6'][] = 1;

$user_class = $user->class;
foreach($compulsory_classes[$user_class] as $current_class) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO relationships (user_id, course_id)
    VALUES (" . $user_class . ", " . $current_class . ")");
}
```

Then use a separate form or function for adding classes that are not compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

The key to getting your tables right is to realise that Students to Subjects is a Many-to-Many relationship.  So you need an intermediate table to establish the relationship.

So you have a table for Students: with say Student_ID, FirstName, LastName as the fields etc

A second table for Subjects: with say Class_ID, SubjectName, Grade, Optional etc

Then an intermediate table say called StudentSubjectLinks which has just three fields as follows;

LinkID:  the ID for the intermediate table.

Student_ID:  which is set up as a Foreign Key linked to the Student_ID in the Student table.

Class_ID: which is set up as a Foreign Key linked to the Class_ID in the Subjects table.